# Add exception to WP Mobile Detector

Tags: mobile

In the function `websitez_detect_mobile_device` in `functions.php` of [WP Mobile Detector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detector/) there is the detection of a mobile device (smartphone). Now I want that my Samsung Galaxy Tab (GT-P5100) is not treated as a smart phone. It should not redirect the user and the user should get the desktop version.

The user agent according to whatsmyuseragent.com is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3;de-de;GT-P5100 Build/IML74K)
>   AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30

How can I add an exception for this device?

Can I use this code?

```
case (preg_match('/GT-P5100/i',$user_agent)); //Android
    $mobile_browser = false;
    $mobile_browser_type = "0"; //Tablet
break;
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

By means of `preg_match` and the like you can only *write rules* for specific devices (in your case the GT-P5100).  What you want to do, however, is to affect **only your device** (meaning: not all Galaxy Tabs).

I'd vote for [setting a cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and act upon it's particular value:

```
setcookie('no_mobile_theme_please', 1, time()+60*60*24*30, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], false, false);
```

Then, you can check for the cookie:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['no_mobile_theme_please']) && (1 == $_COOKIE['no_mobile_theme_please'])) ...
```

If the plugin does not allow for this (i.e., handling an *exception cookie*), you either have to adapt the code yourself, or you might want to write the author about your issue.
Or maybe the plugin offers you a hook, so that you can realize your exception that way...?

Comment: That is the question how I can adapt the code (or add a hook). I still would need the detection of the device and here I could use the same mechanism like the plugin (see my code above). I thought someone had already done that but contacting the theme author is an option. But my example code could work but I have to test it.

Comment: This `$mobile_browser` variable in your code example, is this a global variable of the plugin? If so, then that's all you need. Or where do you want to place the code? Maybe I got you wrong...?

Comment: It seems so that this is the global variable. I would place the code either inside the Android detection or after it (overwriting the settings). But I never tested it. Is this the right way? I mean that I would only change the encoding of one device (a certain Galaxy Tab). It would be better to recognize all Android tablets with a resolution higher than 1024px ...

Comment: To be honest, it ssem that you want to do more than you should do when using a plugin for a peculiar task. If this plugin shows any mobile device the mobile theme, but you would like to handle this resolution based, you might want to search for another plugin - or do it yourself right from the start. Anyway, your code example won't work. When introducing a case, you have to end the line with a colon `:`, not a semicolon. Then, `preg_match` returns bool (meaning true/false), so why do you want do check this (inside a switch)? The whole thing seems a little _off_.

Comment: The thing is that an iPad is recognized well as tablet and you can set an option to exclude tablets. In my case the Galaxy Tab is recognized as smartphone ... But I think I'll leave it as it is. The semicolon is in the code of the plugin author. It is inside a switch statement.